# Android: findViewById returning NULL - couldn't find out whats wrong?

Tags: android, layout

I have the following layout.

When i create `WebView` and `GestureOverlayView` objects in my MainActivity class, it returns `null` for both of the objects.

```
GestureOverlayView gesturesView = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

My Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gestures"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```

When i change the above layout to the following( i moved `android.gesture.GestureOverlayView` inside `LinearLayout`) , it is working fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        android:id="@+id/gestures"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I couldnot figure out what's wrong with my previous layout.

Please someone explain this.

Comment: Did you call setContentView before using findViewById?

Comment: I copied your first layout file and the code to get the views and it works fine for me. Which SDK version are you building against? Also - cleaning the project is definitely worth a try. I find the resource files and the generated R class often get out of sync.

Comment: cleaning the project worked fine. i had tried refreshing the project earlier.but that couldn't solved. now happy. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cleaning the project solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the problems revolving around resources in Android can be solved by cleaning and rebuilding the project.